# USB Ethernet adapter refusing to work on Ubuntu Server

Tags: networking, drivers, server, usb, ethernet

OS: Ubuntu Server 20.04.5 LTS
Hardware: A laptop with i7-6500U & 16GB DDR4 1600

So I have this USB ethernet adapter, "VMAX VIA100 USB3.0 to RJ45".
It works on every device other than this device. I have no idea what to try anymore

Info:

• Doing the `lsusb` command -

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
```

(The adapter is clearly detected)

• `lsmod | grep r8152`

```
   r8152                  69632  0
   mii                    20480  2 usbnet,r8152
```

• `lshw -class network`

```
 *-network:0 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@2:1
       logical name: enx00e04c07002e
       serial: 00:e0:4c:07:00:2e
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.10.11 duplex=full link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
```

•  `sudo ip link set enx00e04c07002e up`

```
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@2:1
       logical name: enx00e04c07002e
       serial: 00:e0:4c:07:00:2e
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.10.11 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
```

It does enable itself, but after reboot disabled itself again.

• `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  version: 2
  wifis: {}
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s31f6:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

---

I've checked the Ethernet cable, no issues there.
I could find no working solutions online. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Added, and thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Networking in all recent server editions of Ubuntu is configured in netplan. Please note that your relevant ethernet interface is enx00e04c07002e. Your netplan file, however, attempts to configure enp0s31f6. Please amend the file to substitute the correct interface; viz:

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enx00e04c07002e:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

Since you are evidently not using wifi, you may safely remove that stanza.

Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Reboot. You should be all set.